# Phone numbers in iPhone's Notes are automtically hyperlinked and hard to see

Tags: iphone

When I type a phone number in iPhone's Notes app, it gets hyperlinked -- against my wishes. It then takes on a yellow font colour, making it impossible to see.  Is there any way to avoid this?

I'm not a fan of cavalier installation of apps (which is why I moved to iPhone from Android), so a native setting is preferred over having to install an app.  I am using iPhone SE.

Even if there was a way to just change the color of the hyperlink from yellow to a colour that is actually visible on white background, that would help.

One answer to this question (below) suggested increasing the font size to compensate for the relative invisibility of yellow text.  It's certainly not ideal, but it seems that I can't even experiment with that.  The Notes app on my iPhone SE doesn't have the formatting buttons found on an iPad (see image below). The respondent's iPhone, also running iOS 11.4, *does* have formatting buttons. If anyone with an *iPhone SE specifically* can confirm whether they have formatting buttons, that may corroborate the speculation that the formatting buttons are absent for the iPhone SE specifically, due to its thin width.

[image]

Comment: What iOS version are you using?  I have 2 devices running 11.4 and I typed a phone number into Notes on both of them.  Neither device adding any linking.  I'm sure it's a setting somewhere to do that or not, I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: iOS 11.4.  I just typed a new Note, first line is "Test" with no quotes, 2nd line empty, 3rd line "612-526-2000".  When I pressed the Done button, the phone number turns yellow and becomes underlined.  Are either of your devices iPhones?

Comment: I see what you're saying now.  I have an iPhone X.  As long as my keyboard is on the screen, the numbers are ok.  Once the keyboard is dismissed, the number changes color and gets the underline.  This is similar to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/182657/88313).  There was no answer there, either.

Comment: I don't think you can change the hyperlinking of numbers with the format xxx-yyy-zzzz nor the hyperlink colour. A simple way to prevent the hyperlinking in the first place is to substitute "~" (tilde) for "-", e.g. "612~526~2000"

Comment: **Thanks!** That is an unfortunate and royal..."inconvenience". I mean, copying phone numbers from web pages or Contacts, and then having to using the tiny soft keys to go back and edit the punctuation at various spots. I'm wondering if I should delete this repeat question. The only consideration for *not* doing so is that I did not find those other posts in my original search. I consider my google-fu to be somewhat decent, so if I didn't find them, perhaps many others won't either.

Comment: The auto-hyperlinking and unreasonable font colour seem all the more nonsensical when one considers that the iPhone is just one device displaying data that might be created, managed, and used across, say, various laptops (Windows, Office) and Exchange Servers. So we're imposing a punctuation workaround that impacts practices across all these devices, some of which may not accept tildes in place of dashes in phone numbers...OK -- </rant off>

Answer (score 1):

One option on your iPad is after to type in your number tap the Aa button on the left side over the keyboard. This won't allow you to change the font color but you can change the font size by selecting Title and make it bold. This increases the visibility by a lot on my iPad. You must do it immediately after typing the number in. [image: Here] Here is the location of the formatting buttons.

Comment: The Notes app on the iPhone doesn't seem to allow manual formatting.

Comment: Yes, it does. I added to my answer to show where formatting buttons are located.

Comment: Can you confirm that it's a picture from an **iPhone**?   just took a screen shot of mine and added it to the originally posted question.  It has none of those formatting buttons.

Comment: mine was from my iPad. I thought they'd be the same. Maybe not.

Comment: My iphone has the same formatting buttons.  I'm running ios 11.4 on both iPhone and iPad.

Comment: too strange!!!  But thats what I get.

Comment: The iPhone SE is very narrow.  The app could very well check the kind of phone decide whether to make formatting available based on that.  Is yours an iPhone SE?

Comment: I don't have an SE in front of me to check but do any of the formatting buttons appear if you turn the phone to landscape orientation?

Comment: That's one of the 1st things I tried, and the answer is "no". But what I found I could do is a long press on the number, allowing me to select it. That presents a popup menu that allows me to copy, paste, bold, underline, etc. Bolding helps a bit, though it's awkward to get to because I have to use tiny scroll buttons on the popup menu.

Comment: @Natsfan may I ask which iPhone do you have (or did, back in 2018)? I found out that those formatting buttons are activated by a "Shortcuts" keyboard option, which does not appear on my iPhone for some reason (it is an iPhone 7+ running iOS 14), but it is there on my much older iPad…