# Stop Apple Notes in iPad auto creating unnecessary hyperlink on handwritten text

Tags: ipad, notes.app, ipados, url, apple-pencil

This is happening sometimes when I start drawing on ipad notes

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does [this iOS answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/308598/88313) work for the iPad version of Notes?

Comment: No. It doesn't work for Sketching in iPad notes app.

Comment: That's strange because I just tried in on my iPad Pro and it worked.  In Notes I wrote a URL with my Pencil.  Notes converted it to a clickable link.  Using the Pencil I circled the link to select it, tapped the Aa button in the Markup tools, selected 'Monospace' and then 'Normal'.  It removed the link.  It also removed the link when I just changed it to Monospace but I wanted to put it back to Normal.  It's flaky, though.  1/2 times I tried, it didn't remove the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not possible to disable content recognition in Notes when drawing, only for typed text:

- [How to turn off hyperlinks in Notes in iOS so you don't accidentally click them?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/182657/37797)

Comment: This is really annoying, is there anyway to reduce this problem?