# How to stop Mac apps from automatically recognising phone numbers?

Tags: terminal, mac, applescript, system-settings, facetime

Whenever there's a string of a few numbers on my Mac, it recognises it as a phone number and tries to dial it (through FaceTime) every time I click it.

Is there a way to stop this, either with System Preferences, AppleScript or Terminal?

Comment: see this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/226079/9058

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off hyperlinks in Notes in iOS so you don't accidentally click them?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182657/how-to-turn-off-hyperlinks-in-notes-in-ios-so-you-dont-accidentally-click-them)

Comment: @nohillside we have a problem. The answer linked to might be correct for this but it is wrong for the linked question. I think some move of answers might be the best

Comment: @mmmmmm I don't see the questions as duplicates, that's why I linked to the specific answer

Comment: @nohillside I agree but SteveChambers and one other think it is one (and by strict reading it is as the question does have an answer elsewhere)

Comment: @mmmmm Well, you could post an answer below :-)

Comment: The answer posted there says to turn off Smart Links, but the option is greyed out

Comment: @Righter Depending on the app, you have to open a new document or page (that was the case with Safari). Which app are you having trouble with?

Comment: @jaume [PDF Professional](https://apps.apple.com/in/app/pdf-professional-annotate-sign/id1071044671?mt=12)

Comment: @Righter Thanks, have you tried unchecking Smart Links with and without open documents? Is it still grayed out? In that case, I'd recommend that you contact the developer of PDF Professional, maybe the functionality is not implemented.